# Google Drive Access using AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

On Google AppEngine i have been through authentication for Google Docs ... access using **AuthSub**  [authshub](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub).

We managed to `AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(..)`.

**QUESTION: Is it possible to follow up and get Access to Google Drive using this token?**

...   new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if AuthSub works with the Google Drive API, but if it does, this code snippet should resolve your problem:

```
new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
  @Override
  public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    // Not sure if this test is necessary as headers might never be null.
    if (headers == null) {
      headers = new HttpHeaders();
      request.setHeaders(headers);
    }
    headers.setAuthorization("AuthSub token=\"<TOKEN>\"");
  }
}).build();
```

**Important**: please be aware that AuthSub is being deprecated and you should try to migrate your application to use OAuth 2.0 as soon as you can.